# User doesn't have attribute "create_logout_url"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a simple button that is written with a logout URL. However, according to this error, a "user" doesn't have a function to create the login URL, when clearly it shows in the API [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions)

```
self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML.replace('___EMAIL___',user.email()).replace('___LOGOUT_URL___',user.create_logout_url('http://www.s-t-h-c.appspot.com')))
```

Comment: Can you show the error traceback, and also show the lines leading up to this line? (We don't even know what is in the variable `user`).

Comment: It should be users.create_logout_url(). Check it is 'users' not user. I think 'user' is customized one. I can't say much from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create_login_url(..)` is not a function on `User`, but a [standalone function](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions) in the `google.appengine.api.users` package.

```
from google.appengine.api import users

users.create_logout_url(url)
```